# Show that $Q:=\{[a,b)\times[c,d): a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}; a < b,c < d\}$ is base of a topology and show that belonging topology is separable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have to show that $Q:=\{[a,b)\times[c,d): a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}; a < b,c < d\}$ is the base of a topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

As far as I know that means I have to show that $Q$ is closed under finite intersections. is that enough? I think I've already got that...
and do I have to mention the case of an empty intersection?

Next I have to show that the belonging topology is separable. Any hint how I can do that?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You need to show that $\mathscr{Q}$ covers $\Bbb R^2$, and that if $B_0,B_1\in \mathscr{Q}$ and $x\in B_0\cap B_1$, then there is a $B\in \mathscr{Q}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq B_0\cap B_1$; see the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28topology%29#Definition_and_basic_properties).

One way to show that second property is to show that $\mathscr{Q}\cup\{\varnothing\}$ is closed under finite intersections. This is most easily done by first showing that the intersection of two members of $\mathscr{Q}\cup\{\varnothing\}$ belongs to $\mathscr{Q}\cup\{\varnothing\}$ and then using induction.

For separability, show that each member of $\mathscr{Q}$ contains points of $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Ok, I'm not completely sure if I´m getting that right. Why do i take Q∪{∅} and show that it´s close under finite intersections instead of just Q?

Comment: @L.muc: Because $\mathscr{Q}$ isn’t closed under finite intersections: it contains disjoint sets, and the intersection of two disjoint members of $\mathscr{Q}$ is $\varnothing$, which is not in $\mathscr{Q}$. Throwing in the empty set is a technical adjustment to avoid this difficulty. Alternatively, you could note that the second property in the definition follows from something slightly weaker than closure under finite intersections: it’s enough that $\mathscr{Q}$ be closed under two-fold intersections of non-disjoint members of $\mathscr{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

The closure under finite intersections is enough. In fact, you *define* the open sets of your topology as arbitrary unions of sets in your family. Then you can *prove* that the intersection of two such open sets is still open. The other axioms of topological spaces are trivial. In particular the empty set is *by definition* the union of an open family of sets in your class.

As for the separability, you can prove it in the following way: the squares with rational sides (i.e. $ a,b,c,d$ are rational) are enough to generate by unions all the open sets defined before.